# How can I adjust the resolution to avoid the damaged area on my screen?

Tags: 11.10, resolution, screen

I have a laptop that has a damaged screen.  The 24 pixels (approximately) on the right side of the screen are damaged (this is definitely not a driver problem, it is physical damage).  It is not a straight bar, but rather a lot of black pixels that ebb and flow with some multicolored pixels around the edges.  I got this from someone so don't know the root cause: possibly water damage?

Anyway, the "power menu as well as any scroll bars (when applications are full screen) are hidden behind this damaged area.  Is there a way I can adjust the screen resolution or dimension so that these right side 24 pixels are not used?  So, the laptop is 1024 x 768.  Can I modify so that it is 1000 x 768 (and the 1000 are the leftmost 1000 pixels, not centered?)?

I was able to try using "xrandr" to force the screen to be 1000 wide, but then it is still centered, so it still only ignores 12 pixels on the right.

Thanks for any help.  This is with Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I think you would need a custom modeline for this, and it could damage your equipment to experiment to fix one up. You may or not care about the old monitor but the graphics card is probably a different matter.

Comment: @JohnSGruber Do you know if *LCD screens* can be damaged by experimenting with custom modelines?

Comment: I think I tried to research that once  but couldn't reach a firm conclusion. At least LCD's don't have those high voltage scanning circuits to go out of control, but I don't know whether or not it's safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a dirty hack... Since your damaged area is on the right side of the screen, you can create a panel with black background, align it to the right, and adjust the size carefully to cover the damaged area:

[image: panel]

Make it opaque, so it looks really black.

Umm.. It seems you can even use a background image, to utilize the remaining good area... I had never use a background image, now I know why it comes..

Comment: @iveand, I hope you will try this, I'd love to know whether this works. Sounds very clever.

Comment: This indeed does seem like a very very good solution.  It would require some addition to Unity in order to add an additional panel, and even then I am not sure if something like the "power button" will shift to the left or not (I don't think it will).  But, of course with lxde or other it would.  Unfortunately, this laptop was for a friend and it has now gone out into the world.  I am going to mark this as the "solution" but unfortunately I can't try it on the specific laptop I had the problem with.  Of course if I get my hands on the laptop again I will try it.

Answer (score -1):

In "System Settings", there is an icon called "displays". Click that, and you should be able to adjust the resolution. Hope this helps!

Comment: No, this doesn't answer the question.  I don't need to just resize the display.  I am trying to manually trim off the right 24 pixels.  I was able to try using "xrandr" to force the screen to be 1000 wide, but then it is still centered, so it only ignores 12 pixels on the right.